# Dataset Loading a WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=server;   database=database; user id=user; password=user"))
{
     connection.Open();
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID ASC", connection))
     {
          SqlDataAdapter reader = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
          reader.Fill(dataSet);
          IDComboBox.DataContext = dataSet; --> This doesn't work
          IDComboBox.Itemsource = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString() --> doesn't work
          IDComboBox.Itemsource = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString() --> doesn't work
          IDComboBox.Itemsource = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows --> doesn't work
          IDComboBox.Itemsource = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns --> doesn't work
          They don't work even with me pairing it the IDComboBox.DataContext = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0] or Columns[0]
     }
     connection.Close();
     connection.Dispose();
}
```

I am needing to fill my combobox in a WPF with the data from my datatable. All I keep finding are the examples that use Combobox.Displaymember, Combobox.Source to do this but a C# WPF application doesn't have these options. How can I load a WPF combobox with data from a dataset or a datatable?

One way that I was doing it before was

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=server; database=database; user id=user; password=user"))
  {
      connection.Open();
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID ASC", connection))
      {
           SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
               {
                   IDComboBox.Items.Add(reader[i].ToString());
               }
           }
       }
       connection.Close();
       connection.Dispose();
  }
```

I know having it for looped into my combobox is very slow if I have large amounts of data so I am wanting to dump it in from a dataset to reduce run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived from [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/bind-combobox-in-wpf/), you'll want to work with the `ItemSource`, `DisplayMemberPath`, and `SelectedValuePath` properties:

```
IDComboBox.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
IDComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["ID"].ToString();
IDComboBox.SelectedValuePath = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["ID"].ToString();
```

And in `xml`:

```
<ComboBox  Name="IDComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Will it still work properly without binding it in the xml? I added those three lines and it pulled all the data over and it is displaying in my combobox.

Comment: @Kyle Yes it will work because implicity the binding *is* occurring. The assignment `Property="{Binding}"` without explicitly defining a binding path defaults to the `Path` property - essentially meaning "set `this.Property` to the evaluated value of `this.DataContext`", which in this case is the `ItemSource`.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF `ComboBox` has an [ItemSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property you can use.

```
IDComboBox.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
```

Comment: Yeah I have been trying to use the itemsource. I can't seem to get it to print the data within the column, all I see is how to print the stuff about that column in relation to the dataset and datatable themselves.                           IDCombobox.Itemsource = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0] then I can't figure out what will give me the data I want. I can get it to display the name of the column.

Comment: The `DataTable.Rows` property contains the actual `DataRow`s with values. You can use this to populate the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`. Alternatively, you could loop through the rows, add the values to a list, then make the list the `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource`.

Comment: When I do the IDComboBox.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows it prints out System.Data.DataRow instead of the actual data..